# Соединение с БД другого сайта (данные известны)

Tags: php

Все было бы просто, но нужно сделать соединение так, чтобы никто, кроме разработчика, не мог узнать данные от БД.
Т.е. у нас есть скрипт, мы собираемся его распространять, нужно делать проверку данных в БД разработчика, разработчик не хочет, чтобы БД была доступна для редактирования всем, а только ему.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну так что мешает сделать отдельного Юзера в БД которому можно только смотреть записи и только.

А если не так то больше информации в студию :)